# Главный проект не находит ресурс из Library Project

Tags: android

Есть `Android Library Project`. Он компилится и запускается без проблем когда сделать из него основной проект. Но когда я его использую именно как `Library Project` для другого проекта высшего уровня, то у меня при запуске выдает ошибку - невозможно найти ресурс `activity` из `library project`. 
Вылетает на этой строчке:

```
setContentView(R.layout.database_view);
```

хотя `database_view.xml` в `library project` гарантированно имеется.

Comment: Недосмотрел манифесты, там были ошибки.
Спасибо за напоминание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уверены, что либу подключаете правильно?

[Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html)